# How to clear contents of an Excel Workbook through vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate data with a master wookbook. When I open the workbook I want a msg box to appear and clear the contents of specific columns in tables in one of the worksheets. I keep getting the "Application-defined or object-defined error". This is the code in my "This workbook" section:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Do you want to clear the totals?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Clear Totals")

If answer = vbYes Then

Call Sheet1.ClearContents_1

End If

End Sub
```

This is my Sheet1 code:

```
Sub ClearContents_1()

Call Loop_Clear_C

Call Loop_Clear_M

Call Clear_S

End Sub

Sub Loop_Clear_C()

For i = 1 To Range("UserTable79").Rows.Count
    Range("UserTable79[Total]")(i) = 0
Next i
End Sub

Sub Loop_Clear_M()

For i = 1 To Range("ServiceTable79").Rows.Count
    Range("ServiceTable79[Total]")(i) = 0
Next i
End Sub

Sub Clear_S()

Range("TotalTable79[Actual Total]").ClearContents

End Sub
```

They worked separately but not together. The msg box comes up but doesn't run the Sheet1 code. How do I call upon this sheet code?
Edit: The Sheet1 code no longer works either.

Comment: You know you don't need the loops as you can clear the contents of multiple cells with something like this `Range("A2").Resize(100,5).ClearContents` which clears the contents of a 100×5 table under "A2".

Comment: The title is misleading, as the question is about clearing parts of a table that includes auto-sum rows (I think), and not clearing entire workbooks (which consists of multiple work sheets).

Answer (score 0):

Often the "Application-defined or object-defined error" message comes up when the range that you're referring to doesn't exist. If you click on Sheet1 to activate it and then try to use the Immediate panel to perform an operation on the ranges you're referring to (e.g. try entering `Range("UserTable79").Select`) do you get an error?

Explicitly specifying the worksheet when calling the function from the "ThisWorkbook" section (e.g. if the worksheet is named "SheetName" then specifying `Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").ClearContents_1` rather than `Call Sheet1.ClearContents_1`) can help.

Also - note that you can clear the entire table ranges or entire columns in `Loop_Clear_C` and `Loop_Clear_M` with `ClearContents` or `EntireColumn.ClearContents` if that's easier.

Comment: Thank you! I’m still quite new at VBA and getting my head around it. Does the EntireColumn.ClearContents syntax clear the header of the table as well? And will continue to work if data is added to that column? That’s why I tried a for loop because I know that data will be added to it. I will continue to keep working on it with your advice!

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment! `EntireColumn.ClearContents` would clear the header (or, more accurately, would set the column header value to "Column1" or some other default text) as well, yes. An easier way to clear the column would be the `Range("TotalTable79[Actual Total]").ClearContents` method that you used in your last function there. Does your Clear_S() subroutine work? If you're adding data to the table, then selecting the column in the table after that should automatically select the entire column including the new cells as far as I know, but I think it depends how you add data.